# how to scroll text on label like marquee

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, marquee

I have text on label which is not appearing completely so i want text to scroll on label from left to right. Please don't suggest numberoflines property as a solution.

Comment: But I assume he wants the text to scroll automatically?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I did something similar using 2 labels in a scroll view...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrolledTextView : UIScrollView
{
    UILabel *label1;
    UILabel *label2;

    NSString *_text;
    NSString *newText;

    CGFloat textWidth;

    BOOL animating;
    BOOL needToUpdateText; 
}

@property (nonatomic, copy, setter = setText:) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval   scrollInterval;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval   scrollDuration;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText : (NSString*) text;

- (void) setText:(NSString *)text;

- (BOOL) textFitsInFrame;

@implementation ScrolledTextView

@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize scrollDuration;
@synthesize scrollInterval;

- (void) adjustLabelsForNewText : (NSString*) text andParentFrame : (CGRect) frame
{
    _text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  ", text];

    CGSize textSize = [[self text] sizeWithFont:[label1 font]     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(textSize.width * 2, textSize.height)];

    textWidth = textSize.width;

    [label1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, textWidth, frame.size.height)];
    [label1 setText:[self text]];

    if([self textFitsInFrame])
    {
        [label2 removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else 
    {
        [label2 setFrame:CGRectMake([label1 frame].size.width, 0.0, textWidth, frame.size.height)];
        [label2 setText:[self text]];

        if( ! [[self subviews] containsObject:label2])
        {
            [self addSubview:label2];
        }

        [self beginScrolling];
    }
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText : (NSString*) text
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

        animating = NO;
        needToUpdateText = NO;

        [self setScrollDuration:10.0];
        [self setScrollInterval:2.0];

        label1 = [UILabel new];
        label2 = [UILabel new];

        [label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [self addSubview:label1];

        [self adjustLabelsForNewText:text andParentFrame:frame];        
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    if(needToUpdateText)
    {
        animating = NO;
        needToUpdateText = NO;
        [self adjustLabelsForNewText:@"" andParentFrame:[self frame]];
        [self adjustLabelsForNewText:newText andParentFrame:[self frame]];
        newText = nil;

        return;
    }

    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    [self beginScrolling];
}

- (void) beginScrolling
{
    animating = YES;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[self scrollDuration]];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:[self scrollInterval]];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(textWidth, 0.0)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL) textFitsInFrame
{
    return textWidth <= [self frame].size.width;
}

- (void) setText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(animating)
    {
        newText = text;
        needToUpdateText = YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        [self adjustLabelsForNewText:text andParentFrame:[self frame]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we implement the textAlignment and textcolor with this code>?

Answer (score 0):

if u appear a complete string in label using this line
     CGSize labelsize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
    then in CGRectMark(10,10, label.width,100 );

marquee are based on scroll content-size,if u set content-size(200,300),mean take that value to compare with x and y value to set a marquee.

regard
CNSivakumar